# API Gateway authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, aws-api-gateway

I am building a web site as a part of a project of mine and I got a bit stuck.

I created an API Gateway that will help me communicate with my AWS Lambda (That is basically the backend side that is calling a text-to-speech model).

I believe my API Gateway is set properly, as when I try to test the POST method, I get back the expected result. However, when I try to access the API using the same request from my website directly, I get a 401 UNAUTHORIZED.

This is my resource:
[image]
And by testing that works I meant using the TEST button and supply the expected body.

I can tell that the API Gateway testing does state that when triggered, they invoke the method directly and skip the authorization process:

> Make a test call to your method. When you make a test call, API Gateway skips authorization and directly invokes your method

I tried setting an Authorizer from the Gateway interface, create an API-key for my API, but no success so far.
In the above picture, "auth" is the Authorizer I set.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly did you test your method so it worked? What is the difference between this test and the actual use case? Are there any more details to the error available? Have you tried activating logging on the GW to see what it reports?

Comment: I attached a screenshot of the Gateway, I tested it using the "TEST" button. I believe that the difference is that the test is skipping the authorization process but I find it difficult to pass this step.
Regarding the logging, The request does not get past the request step so on CloudTrail none of my requests are shown, I was able only to get some info from it using the browser's dev tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer to the exact question, but what solved the issue for me was the understanding that changes in API Gateway takes a few minutes to deploy.
What happened is every time I deployed a change I immediately tried to access the API from my web page and this way debugging was impossible.

So - if a change is made on API Gateway, wait a few minutes before you try again :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to create a usage plan under API GW and associate your key with the usage plan, then you will be able to access the API,

Don't forget to pass the key as a header in your request, with header key-value pair "x-api-key: your-api-key" .

Read more about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html)